# Hosting create-react-app on gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, heroku, react-router, github-pages, create-react-app

I'm trying to host this repo ( https://github.com/bcravens/WorkoutsClient ) on gh-pages and connect it to my backend hosted on heroku but after following the github pages guide on the create-react-app README ( https://bcravens.github.io/WorkoutsClient/#github-pages ) its coming up blank and I'm unsure where I went wrong.

When hosting locally I was using bashhistory but as directed by the guide I simply changed 'bash' to 'hash' in my project and added /#/ to the url, is there more to this that I'm missing?

Also while hosting locally I connected my front-end to my back-end with proxy in package.json file. Can I just change this to my heroku url or do I need something like cors?

Note: I'm using the gh-pages branch

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [your repo](https://github.com/bcravens/WorkoutsClient/blob/master/src/index.js#L31), you are attempting to use the `browserHistory` when it should be `hashHistory`

```
render((
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={hashHistory} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: I created a gh-pages branch ( https://github.com/bcravens/WorkoutsClient/tree/gh-pages ) and switched bash to hash

Comment: Where? When I look through the source code there I see a `browserHistory` instance being passed to the `<Router>`.